# Transfer value from drop down to textbox

Tags: jquery, html

How I can insert the value in text box from a drop down list? I Only need to choose the box and appear in the text box without be able to edit.

```
     <form method="post" action="/{{site | url.encode}}/checkout">
            <input type="hidden" name="oneitem">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Online Bill Pay">
            <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="{{site}}">



    <select name=amount id="money">
    <option value="50.00">FACEBOOK $50.00</option>
    <option value="100.00">FACEBOOK $100.00</option>
            <p>
                <input name="amount" value="money" size="5">
            </p>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, a `select` can't contain a `p`

Comment: Something like this?:  `$('#someInputElement').val($('#someSelectElement').val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch your HTML syntax, or all bets are off.

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="whatevs">You heard</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="textbox">

$('#dropdown').on('change',function() {
    $('#textbox').val($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work

```
<select id="testSelect">
    <option vale="Test1">Test</option>
    <option value="Test1">Test 1</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="testtextbox"/>
```

javascript

```
$('#testSelect').on('change',function() {
    $("#testtextbox").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the select tag and quote all the attributes. Drop the input box and its paragraph outside the select element. Assign an id to the input box for easier selecting (I used `text`). After that, try something like this:

```
$('#money').change(function(){
    $('#text').val($('#money).val());
});
```